# Finding nilpotent elements in a quotient ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ideals, nilpotence

Which are nilpotent elements of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^5-3x^2)\times\mathbb{Z}/(12)$?

I tried to decompose in this way: $$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^5-3x^2)\times\mathbb{Z}/(12)\cong\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)\times\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-3)\times\mathbb{Z}/(3)\times\mathbb{Z}/(4)$$ so i thought that nilpotent elements are only:
$$(0,0,0,2), (x,0,0,2) \ \  \mbox{and} \ \  (x,0,0,0).$$

I don't know if I am right, because i tried another approach considering the intersetion of all prime ideals of that ring and i don't know to understand if the result is the same.

Comment: In place of $x$ you can also use $ax$ with any $a\in\Bbb{Q}$ as the first component.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Are there any other nilpotent elements?

Comment: No. Joel's answer gives the argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nilpotent elements of the product are obtained as the tuples of the nilpotent elements of single factors.

Comment: But if i consider prime ideals of that ring I obtain $((x)\times(1)), \ ((x^3-3)\times(1)), \ ((1)\times(2)), \ ((1)\times(3))$.

Is their intersection equal to those 3 elements I listed in my question?

Comment: Yes, the intersection of the latter is $(1)\times(6)$. It is more difficult to show that $(x)\cap (x^3-3)=(x^2)$..

Comment: But is not $(x)\cap(x^3-3)=((x)(x^3-3))$?

Comment: Sorry, I'm clearly wrong. The one you said it's the intersection by Chinese Remainder Theorem.